# Get total Profile by weeks with no of week from user regirstered

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one is "complete_bets" and another is "users".In the first table, I have a column profit in which users can enter their profit and loss day by day, Here is table screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/f4fmw7

A user table has a column 'user_registered' in which we stored the date when a user did register.

I want to get a profit of any user by weeks, means profit with the number of weeks as a member on the website.

Right now I'm using this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(`date_added`), '/', WEEK(`date_added`)) AS lol, 
WEEK(`date_added`) AS week_name, SUM(profit) as overallProfit 
FROM wpdw_complete_bets 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
GROUP BY week_name 
ORDER BY date_added ASC
```

But it's getting me a week of the year but I want profit/loss week wise with the number of the weeks as a member on the website.

I wants result like that

```
userId  no_of_week_user_register  profit
1              1                    100
1              2                    120
1              4                    150
```

Where no_of_week_user_register is like after registration of first week user gets 100 as profile in second week he get 120 and in 4th week form their registration he get 150.

Please let know how can I write my query to get it working, any kind of help would be much appreciable.

Comment: post sample data and the expected result as formatted text, not as pictures or links.

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look now

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: May I know why negative vote ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(`date_added`) AS week_name, 
   SUM(IF(profit > 0, profit, 0)) as profit,
   SUM(IF(profit < 0, profit, 0)) as loss
FROM wpdw_complete_bets 
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY week_name 
ORDER BY week_name ASC
```

EDIT:
So you want the number of weeks since the user registered?

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, ?user_create_date, `date_added`) AS week_name, 
   SUM(IF(profit > 0, profit, 0)) as profit,
   SUM(IF(profit < 0, profit, 0)) as loss
FROM wpdw_complete_bets 
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY week_name 
ORDER BY week_name ASC
```

Comment: Really thanks for your answer, but it will give week no of year but I wants the week number from user registered, like after first week of regirster user get 100 as profit and in second week from regirstration user get 120 as profilt like that .. I hope now you understand my concern, the user regirstration date in usres table